# SSRS: как получить определения отчетов?

Tags: sql-server

Как получить определения отчетов (*.rdl)?

Разместить отчеты на сервере отчетов могу, используя, к примеру, Business Intelligence Development Studio, или через Report Manager передать файл, а как скачать определения этих отчетов?

К примеру, захожу на http://<server>/Reports, вижу все отчеты, могу их выполнить, а как скачать их определения, сами rdl'ки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из всплывающего меню конкретного отчета надо выбрать "Загрузить". Если этот пункт у вас отсутствует - значит вам не хватает прав на выгрузку, есть права только на выполнение.

Comment: А можно как-нибудь разом все отчеты загрузить, вместе с общими источниками данных и общими наборами данных?

Comment: Да, можете дернуть их ил БД ReportServer'а (если права есть). Немного по структуре можно почитать здесь: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2012/10/09/when-someone-deletes-a-shared-data-source-in-ssrs.aspx  
Когда переносил отчеты с одного RS на другой сильно помогло.

Comment: Через интерфейс - не знаю такого способа. Через базу - выше ответили со ссылкой, можно посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.aspx